# Time for launched object to reach point in space

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity

I am attempting to calculate the time required for an object launched perpendicular to the surface of the earth at escape velocity to reach an arbitrary point in space (neglecting rotational velocity, although I am not opposed to adding that factor).  My initial thought was to divide the distance to said point by the escape velocity but that does not take into account the affects of gravity with changing distance.  Energy equations seem to be semi useless as you can't get information about time from them.  With that being said I attempted to break the problem into discrete steps and calculate the time using a sum of the infinite variety (or whatever n precision I want). Below you will find my scratch work.

[image: maths... ish]

This works I suppose but I have to calculate it using a discrete amount of steps with python.  Any hints on how I would go about solving this using an integral?  A method for deriving a neat equation would be ideal.  I am fine having sympy or mathematica solve the integral if it is extremely hairy.  This is a physics class and not a math class after all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I'd do it is with a differential equation rather than with energy methods. The situation we have here is:
$$\frac{d^2r}{dt^2}=-\frac{MG}{r^2}$$

Now let $v=dr/dt$. Then (remembering the chain rule), 
$$\frac{dv}{dt}=-\frac{MG}{r^2}\\
\frac{dv}{dr}\frac{dr}{dt}=-\frac{MG}{r^2}\\
\frac{dv}{dr}v=-\frac{MG}{r^2}\\
vdv=-\frac{MG}{r^2}dr\\
\frac{1}{2}v(t)^2+C=\frac{MG}{r(t)} $$

Now let's use the fact that when $r\rightarrow \infty$, $v\rightarrow 0$ (escape velocity, remember?)

$$v(t)^2=\frac{2MG}{r(t)}\\
\frac{dr}{dt}=\sqrt{\frac{2MG}{r(t)}}\\
\sqrt{r}{dr}=\sqrt{2MG}dt\\
\frac{2}{3}r^{3/2}+C=\sqrt{2MG}t$$

Now one more initial condition. At $t_0$, $r=R_E$, so

$$\frac{2}{3}R_E^{3/2}+C=0\\
C=-\frac{2}{3}R_E^{3/2}$$

Finally, we can find the time t as a function of the distance $r$ from the center.

$$t=\sqrt{\frac{2}{9MG}}\left(r^{3/2}-R_E^{3/2}\right)$$

Awesome question, thanks for asking it (I'd been thinking about this problem earlier today and couldn't come up with a solution. I saw your question, thought about it some more, and found it :) ).

Answer (score 1):

The [*vis viva* equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vis-viva_equation) for an on a parabolic trajectory about the Earth is
$$v(t)^2 = \frac {2GM_\oplus} {r(t)}$$
The subscript on mass, $M_\oplus$ is the [symbol used widely in astronomy](http://www.universetoday.com/35931/symbols-of-the-planets/) to indicate the Earth.

For an object on a radial trajectory, there transverse component of velocity is zero, and thus $v(t) = \frac {dr}{dt}$. Since the object is leaving the Earth, it's radial velocity will be positive. Taking the positive square root of the *vis viva* trajectory yields
$$\frac{dr}{dt} = \sqrt{\frac{2GM_\oplus}{r}}$$
Rearranging the above yields
$$\sqrt{\frac r {2GM_\oplus}} dr = dt$$
This is perfectly suited to solving the problem at hand, which is to determine time as a function of radial distance. Integrating the above yields
$$t(r) = t_0 + \sqrt{\frac 2 9 \frac {r^3}{GM_\oplus}}$$
where $t_0$ is a constant of integration. Assuming the launch happens at the Earth's equatorial radius $r_{eq}$ and time is arbitrarily set to zero at launch, the integration constant becomes
$$t_0 = -\sqrt{\frac 2 9 \frac {r_{eq}^3}{GM_\oplus}}$$
and thus
$$t(r) = \sqrt{\frac 2 9} \left(\sqrt{\frac {r^3}{GM_\oplus}} - \sqrt{ \frac {r_{eq}^3}{GM_\oplus}}\right)$$

**Aside**
It's a good habit to get into the practice of using a body's [gravitational parameter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_gravitational_parameter) $\mu_{\text{body}}$ instead of $GM_{\text{body}}$. The reason is that the gravitational parameter of some object can oftentimes be directly deduced by investigating how things interact gravitationally with that object. This most certainly is the case for the Sun, the planets, and several of the moons. Scientists know the Earth's gravitational parameter $\mu_\oplus \approx$ 398600.4418 km<sup>3</sup>/s<sup>2</sup> to nine places of accuracy. Contrast that high precision with the universal gravitational constant and the Earth's mass, which are only known to four places of accuracy.

Comment: Doesn't the vis viva equation only apply to orbiting bodies, not a launched object that doesn't necessarily orbit?

Comment: Your object is "orbiting". In particular, it's on a degenerate radial parabolic orbit. The *vis viva* equation, $v^2 = \mu \left(\frac 2 r - \frac 1 a\right)$, still applies. That equation is just conservation of energy given Keplerian motion. In that equation, $a$ is the semi-major axis length. This is positive for ellipses, negative for hyperbolae, and infinite for parabolae. The vis viva equation this simplifies to $v^2 = \frac {2\mu} r$ in the case of a parabolic trajectory.

Comment: Ah, well your physics foo is superior to mine.  I would choose your answer but the other human answered first and I like the idea of solving it as a second order differential anyway.  Still, I appreciate your willingness to help.